How to set ajax success data to Nop Editor textbox in nopcommerce
I am working in nopcommerce 4.60.6. In that I am using one nop-editor textbox.
Here is the view code
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <nop-label asp-for="TotalLabour" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <nop-editor asp-for="TotalLabour" />
        <input type="button" value="@T("Admin.Awaz.ClickForLabourAmount")" id="btn_getlabour" class="btn btn-primary" />                        
    </div>
</div>

Now, when I click on btn_getlabour button at that time ajax should be called (which is working perfect).
Here is the ajax code,
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btn_getlabour').bind('click', function () {            
            if (document.getElementById('NetWeight').value == 0) {
                alert("First Enter The NetWeight...!!!");
            }
            else {
                var postData = {
                    netWeight: document.getElementById('NetWeight').value
                };
                $.ajax({
                    cache: false,
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "@(Url.Action("GetLabourAmt"))",
                    data: postData,
                    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {                         
                        $("#TotalLabour").val(data);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>

Ajax function code by controller side
public virtual async Task<IActionResult> GetLabourAmt(decimal netWeight)
{
    if (!await _permissionService.AuthorizeAsync(StandardPermissionProvider.ManageCategories))
        return AccessDeniedView();            
    var labourPerGm = _labourMasterService.GetLabourAsync();
    var result = Convert.ToDecimal(labourPerGm.Result.Labour) * netWeight;
    return Json(result);
}

Now as per the code I am getting result perfectly and that result value I want to set to nop-editor textbox.
from this code $("#TotalLabour").val(data); I am getting value but it not showing in nop-editor textbox. But when I focused (Clicked) on nop-editor textbox then value is showing.
Is there any problem in code?
